# Python API request getting error AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'args'

Tags: python, api

I have an API where I am pulling the results, but after updating my SDK to Python v10, i an not able to run pull from API and I am getting

> AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'get'

I tried updating to  vulns = dx_request.args.get(  and getting error

> ```
> AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'args'
> ```

Any thoughs! Thx

```
import os
import json
import requests
from http import HTTPStatus

client_id = ""
client_secret = ""

os.environ["DX_GATEWAY"] = "http://api.com"
os.environ["DX_CLIENT_ID"] = client_id
os.environ["DX_CLIENT_SECRET"] = client_secret

dx_request = requests.Request()

path = "/path/to/api"

params = {
    "Type": "abc",
    "Id": "def",
    "limit": 999,
    "Category": "abc"
}

params_str = "&".join([f"{k}={v}" for k, v in params.items()])
url = "?".join([path, params_str])

vulns = dx_request.get( ##also tried dx_request.args.get(
    url,
    version=1,
)

if vulns.status_code != int(HTTPStatus.OK):
    raise RuntimeError("API call did not return expected response: " + str(vulns))

response_data = vulns.json()    
print(json.dumps(response_data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [official documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Try writing:

```
vulns = requests.get(url)
```

Comment: the url is now fixed, but i there is an issue with the version=1, 
getting error `TypeError: Session.request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'version`. 
 

`vulns = requests.get(
    url=url,
    version=1,`

Comment: If i remove version=1, then i am getting invalid url error

Answer (score 0):

`requests` package doesn't have a `get` attribute, so you can write code using `Session` objects instead like this

```py
dx_requests = requests.Session()
dx_requests.get(url=url)
# do another stuff
```

and if you have a problem regarding version headers, i think you need to set the version argument in request headers instead passed directly on the `get` parameter, so it will look like this

```py
headers = {
    "x-api-version": 1 # im assuming you want to do this
}
dx_requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
```